# Consul service fails to start

Tags: terraform, consul, hashicorp-vault

Trying to setup a single node Consul on Ubuntu 18.04, using version: `Consul v1.8.4`. I am using my own user to start,

My consul.service  file looks like this

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/consul/bin/consul agent –server –ui  –data-dir=/temp/consul –bootstrap-expect=1 –node=vault –bind=192.168.37.128 –config-dir=/etc/consul.d
```

`sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
`sudo systemctl start consul`

The service fails to start - complaining about `Unexpected extra arguments`

```
journalctl -xe -u consul

Unexpected extra arguments: [–server –ui –data-dir=/temp/consul –bootstrap-expect=1 –node=vault –bind=192.168.37.128 –conf
Oct 02 23:50:25 ubuntu2 systemd[1]: consul.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 02 23:50:25 ubuntu2 systemd[1]: consul.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

## Update Issue 2

failed to parse /etc/consul.d/ui.json: invalid character `'â' looking for beginning of object key string`

`ui.json`  - the issue seems `“ ”`  - they need to be `" "` - as below now:

```
{
"addresses": {
"http": "0.0.0.0"
  }
}
```

So these unicode chars need to be taken care of - cut-n-paste issues across editors - *best use text editors or directly in console*.

**If anyone has best practice ideas.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the options specified in your systemd unit are prefixed with a en dash (`–`: Unicode 0x2013) instead of a hyphen (`-`: Unicode 0x2d). See [Wikipedia: Hyphens and Dashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Hyphens_and_dashes) for more info.

The proper syntax to specify the options is:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/consul/bin/consul agent -server -ui -data-dir=/temp/consul -bootstrap-expect=1 -node=vault -bind=192.168.37.128 -config-dir=/etc/consul.d
```

Comment: Thanks that took care of that issue. Dont know how this transposition happened? And how do you detect? But now next issue - the cause perhaps seems similar - cant see - posting in main.

Comment: Detected the issue with `“ ”` and fixed it with `" "` .  **It all works now** - till the next issue.